# How to calculate Time complexity for a program?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to learn Time complexity of a programs.

I studied many blogs but, Each one is trying to explain different.

Can any one explain me clearly with programs as example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too broad. Have you read ["About `time-complexity`"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/time-complexity/info)? It has a few links to start with.

Comment: "Many blogs" do a very poor job of this. There's a reason people pay for books. If you're serious about learning, then get a serious algorithm text (CLRS or equivalent), then read, study, think, and practice for as long as it takes. If you don't have the requisite math, go get that first.